# Are there any downsides of creating many instances of the same class?

Tags: objective-c

I am re-writing my whole app from scratch and I got wondering if there's any difference and/or downside of creating multiple instances of the same class.

For example

```
MyOtherClass *my_class = [[MyOtherClass alloc] init];

for(int a = 0; a < 100; a++) {
    [my_class https_create_account:@"user_account"];
}
```

versus

```
for(int a = 0; a < 100; a++) {
    [[[MyOtherClass alloc] init] https_create_account:@"user_account"];
}
```

Does the second one use more resources or memory or does it really not matter ?

EDIT:

Here's the function I'm calling from MyMainClass which is a subclass of UIViewController. The function 'https_create_account' is in MyOtherClass which is a subclass of NSObject.

```
-(void)https_create_account :(NSString *)post_data {
   NSDictionary *headers = @{@"accept": @"application/json"};
   NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"account": post_data, @"user_id": post_data, @"main_account": post_data};
   [[UNIRest post:^(UNISimpleRequest *request) {
       [request setUrl:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/create_account/", SERVER_API_URL]];
       [UNIRest timeout:60];
       [request setHeaders:headers];
       [request setParameters:parameters];
   }] asJsonAsync:^(UNIHTTPJsonResponse* response, NSError *error) {
   // result
   }];
}
```

So what would be the best way of calling the function from inside the MyMainClass ?

Comment: What exactly is `calculate_this` doing?

Comment: Most of the time it's API calls to our server, like submitting a score or getting the latest scores. I was mostly wondering if I should just create one instance of the class through AppDelegate and always call it from there, but I'm not sure if it'd have the same affects as calling `[[[MyOtherClass alloc] init] calculate_this];` every time.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense that the two options for calling this method would produce equivalent results. If the outcome of the method doesn't depend on the instance that it's called from, it's hard to see why it's even an instance method in the first place. It sounds like it should be a function or maybe a class method.

Comment: OH you're right! I should just call the method like `[[MyOtherClass alloc] calculate_this];` since it's only a function, right ?, sorry if I sound dumb, new to programming.

Comment: The second is almost certainly using more resources. But we can't really tell you much about how your `MyOtherClass` will behave in either scenario since we can't see its code at all. But when I see someone allocating an instance of a class just to call a single method on it, especially in a loop like that, they're usually doing something wrong.

Comment: No, you don't want to ever call a method on a class after only calling `alloc` and not one of your `init` methods.

Comment: And you should not "call" `[MyOtherClass calculate_this]`, either. Objects do not bundle functionality, but a state and methods working on that state. They are *not* modules.

Comment: Hey sorry about the delay, I've updated my question with the function I'm calling and from where I'm calling it, I would appreciate it a lot if you could take a look at it!